# Create NUGET package to support Both Asp.Net MVC and Asp.Net core MVC

Tags: nuget-package

I have created the library project with **TragetFramework is .NetFramework 4.5**

I released the library project as Nuget package. By using this Nuget package developer can able to Create Razor Html control in Asp.Net MVC project. This is working as we expected.

My problem is now I want to support Asp.Net core MVC project also. How can I create NUGET package to support Both Asp.Net MVC and Asp.Net core MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible. MVC packages have to target **net40/net45/net46**. But ASP.Net Core packages have to target **netcoreapp1.0**.

Comment: What i need to do to support both

Comment: You should maintain separate packages for each platform.